# Error in the installation of the Qemu in Debain 10

Tags: linux, debian, gnu, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to write the ARM assembly programs compiling them using the GNU toolchain and execute and test them in Qemu. My host os is Windows 7 and I perform these operations in the virtual machine Debian 10.

- For installing Qemu used the command steps followed

  1. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.
  2. apt-get install qemu

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install qemu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qemu is already the newest version (1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

3. apt-get install qemu-system-arm qemu

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install qemu-system-arm qemu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qemu is already the newest version (1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u5).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-system-arm : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libcapstone3 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libfdt1 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libspice-server1 (>= 0.13.1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libvdeplug2 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libvirglrenderer0 (>= 0.7.0) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-system-gui (= 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: qemu-utils but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ipxe-qemu (>= 1.0.0+git-20131111.c3d1e78-1~) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-efi-aarch64 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: qemu-efi-arm but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It seems you mixed package sources of different distributions (vendor/version) or you added some external package repositories (dependencies checking and installability is checked often and automatically on Debian official packages).

Comment: @ Giacomo Catenazzi . Could you please say how to make it "normal Debian".

Answer (score 0):

try to enter:
"apt install -f"
It should help you